# Nested array in JObject

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, api, json.net

I am working with OutBrain Api .

In my code, the function `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` returns a json object, which looks like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "2016-10",
        "fromDate": "2016-10-01",
        "toDate": "2016-10-30"
      },
      "metrics": {
        "impressions": 1164823829,
        "clicks": 2660235,
        "conversions": 2228,
        "spend": 463546.37,
        "ecpc": 0.17,
        "ctr": 0.23,
        "conversionRate": 0.08,
        "cpa": 208.05
      }
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "2016-09",
        "fromDate": "2016-09-01",
        "toDate": "2016-09-30"
      },
      "metrics": {
        "impressions": 959483548,
        "clicks": 2245759,
        "conversions": 1777,
        "spend": 385899.67,
        "ecpc": 0.17,
        "ctr": 0.23,
        "conversionRate": 0.08,
        "cpa": 217.16
      }
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "2016-08",
        "fromDate": "2016-08-01",
        "toDate": "2016-08-31"
      },
      "metrics": {
        "impressions": 980319229,
        "clicks": 2621017,
        "conversions": 1818,
        "spend": 358970.61,
        "ecpc": 0.14,
        "ctr": 0.27,
        "conversionRate": 0.07,
        "cpa": 197.45
      }
    }
  ],
  "totalResults": 3,
  "summary": {
    "impressions": 3104626606,
    "clicks": 7527011,
    "conversions": 5823,
    "spend": 1208416.65,
    "ecpc": 0.16,
    "ctr": 0.24,
    "conversionRate": 0.08,
    "cpa": 207.52
  }
}
```

I am trying to reach the data inside every "metadata" and "metrics" which are all in the "results" but it seems that my code doesn't work.

My Code:

```
string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    JObject campaignData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseData);

                    Dictionary<string, dynamic> mediaCampaigns = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
                    if (campaignData != null)
                    {
                        if (campaignData["totalResults"].ToString() != "1" & campaignData["totalResults"].ToString() != "0")
                        {
                            foreach (var campItem in campaignData)
                            {
                                mediaCampaigns.Add(campItem["@results"]["@metadata"]["@fromDate"]ToString(), new
                                {
                                    cost = campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@spend"] != null ? campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@spend"] : 0,
                                    clicks = campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@clicks"] != null ? campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@clicks"] : 0,
                                    impressions = campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@impressions"] != null ? campaignData["@results"]["@impressions"]["@impressions"] : 0,
                                    conversions = campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@conversions"] != null ? campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@conversions"] : 0,
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mediaCampaigns.Add(campaignData["@results"]["@metadata"]["@fromDate"].ToString(), new
                            {
                                cost = campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@spend"] != null ? campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@spend"] : 0,
                                clicks = campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@clicks"] != null ? campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@clicks"] : 0,
                                impressions = campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@impressions"] != null ? campaignData["@results"]["@impressions"]["@impressions"] : 0,
                                conversions = campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@conversions"] != null ? campaignData["@results"]["@metrics"]["@conversions"] : 0,
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

I would like to get some help, thanks!

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I just cant access the data inside the json object. the foreach loop put nothing in the Dictionary .

Comment: Why don't you deserialize it into an object? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: ok i could try , but how its will help me ?

Comment: you can access it from the list once you deserialized inside foreach, try the intellisense it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code the `RootObject` is a class generated by [this](http://json2csharp.com/) tool:

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
Dictionary<string, dynamic> mediaCampaigns = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
foreach (var item in test.results)
{
    mediaCampaigns.Add(item.metadata.fromDate, new 
    {
        cost = item.metrics.spend,
        clicks = item.metrics.clicks,
        impressions = item.metrics.impressions,
        conversions = item.metrics.conversions
    });
}
```

This works for me. Also change

```
ReadAsStringAsync()
```

to

```
ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Thanks ! its helped me !